# how to display jquery page(inside a div) using javascript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

here is my problem, i call this method and what it does is

post some data on server using jQuery, i want to display page using result i recieve from server

my page index.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    // other page content
            <div id="divrightButton">

            <!-- calling loginSubmit which calls loginPostData-->   
            <a class="bluebutton" href="#" onclick="loginSubmit(); return false;">Login</a>

            </div>
        </form>
</div>

<!--main page-->
<div data-role="page" id="mainMenu">

     Main menu
</div>
```

here is the piece of code from javascript, **quick thing loginSubmit() calls loginPostData** ,loginSubmit make a json object and pass it to loginPostData

```
function loginPostData(jsonRequest)
{
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/edserve/MobileServlet", 
            JSON.stringify( jsonRequest), 
            function(data) 
            {
                var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
                //var object = JSON.parse(json_text);
                //alert(obj);
                alert(obj);
                if(data.status=="success")
                {
                    //display main page
                    //$('#mainMenu').show(); <-- this does not give desired result
                }
                else
                {
                    if(data.message=="user not verified")
                    {
                        //display verification page
                    }   
                    if(data.message=="no user exist with this usname")
                    {
                        //set focus to username
                        $("#username").focus();
                    }   
                }   
        }, "json");
}
```

HOW TO SHOW MAIN MENU WHEN THERE IS SUCCESS, the entire code of html is in single file in different div's

---

use this code to redirect/display the particular div tag/element

`$.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu",{allowSamePageTransition: true });`

and also download following css file, its a must for transitioning between pages/div elements

[jquery.mobile.transitions.css](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/ca9df1197a9748ee7448fb9b28c14c41d80d4601/themes/default/jquery.mobile.transitions.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
 $.mobile.changePage( "#mainMenu", { allowSamePageTransition: true });
```

and check this link

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: i tried this method , it works perfectly, it directs to where i want, but i have to refresh the it load the page

Comment: I can not understand what you said.. Can yoe explain againa?

Comment: i said the page url changes and it goes to main menu on success
`http://localhost:8080/edserve/mclient/index.html#mainMenu`

but, the problem is nothing is displayed, it just blank page
and the content are displayed, only when i refresh

Comment: Thanks a lot @stay_hungry
it was problem with firefox, your solution works splendid on Google Chrome

Thanks a lot men :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the jquery load function for this http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: i tried method from this site `$('#result').load('index.html#mainMenu');`, it works perfectly, it directs to where i want, but i have to refresh the it load the page

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
function loginPostData(jsonRequest)
    {
        $.post("http://localhost:8080/edserve/MobileServlet", 
                JSON.stringify( jsonRequest), 
                function(data) 
                {
                    var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
                    //var object = JSON.parse(json_text);
                    //alert(obj);
                    alert(obj);
                    if(data.status=="success")
                    {
                        $.mobile.changePage( "#mainMenu"); // main menu div id..
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(data.message=="user not verified")
                        {
                            //display verification page
                        }   
                        if(data.message=="no user exist with this usname")
                        {
                            //set focus to username
                            $("#username").focus();
                        }   
                    }   
            }, "json");
    }
```

Comment: i tried this method , it works perfectly, it directs to where i want, but i have to refresh the it load the page

Comment: try this..

window.location = 'filename#mainMenu';

Comment: same thing i have to refresh page, only then i can see page contents