# jquery redirects to page element, but nothing is displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to display jquery page(inside a div) using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828089/how-to-display-jquery-pageinside-a-div-using-javascript)

here is my javascript code

```
function loginPostData(jsonRequest)
{
    alert("hello");
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/edserve/MobileServlet", 
            JSON.stringify(jsonRequest), 
            function(data) 
            {
                var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
                alert(obj);
                if(data.status=="success")
                {
                    <!--problem lies here-->
                    $.mobile.changePage( "#mainMenu");
                    //$('#result').load('index.html#mainMenu');
                    // . load also give the same result
                }
                else
                {
                    if(data.message=="user not verified")
                    {
                        //display verification page 
                    }   
                }   
            }, "json");
}
```

**PROBLEM**: the jquery loads the main menu page, but nothing is displayed, untill i refresh the page

just a quick reference of my page

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    // other page content
            <div id="divrightButton">

            <!-- calling loginSubmit which calls loginPostData method/function-->   
            <a class="bluebutton" href="#" onclick="loginSubmit(); return false;">Login</a>

            </div>
        </form>
</div>

<!--main page-->
<div data-role="page" id="mainMenu">

     Main menu
</div>
```

i also came to know that there is some issue in jquery with same page transition
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2529

but how to fix these issue, i dont have any clue on this node
just in case, i have also tried the following for redirection/loading

```
$.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu",{allowSamePageTransition: true }); 
$('#result').load('index.html#mainMenu');
$.mobile.changePage( $("#mainMenu"));
```

none is working, what i mean is it works but results are same, nothing is displayed

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? and what exactly is happening ? are you trying to load remote content ? because all you are doing with the code above is to show "Main Menu" - ie change the page

Comment: I think you need to strip down your code so you can present us only the code that is needed to explain the actual problem. This makes it easier to reproduce.

Comment: To follow your example, can you also provide the source code for method 'loginsubmit()'? And how do you call the method 'loginPostData()'? Does an error message occure in the error console of Firefox, Chrome or Safari?

Comment: @Akhil Jain if nothing displayed then could you please show me the XHR response that shows what data is being returned in your query.

Comment: @reporter not at all,no error is showed up in the firebug

Comment: @Ohgodwhy here is the data that is returned from server

`{"opcode":"login","status":"success","message":"login succesful","data":{"first name":"asd","last name":"asd","email id":"asd@asd.com","mobile no":"9976543210","gender":"male"}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code to redirect/display the particular div element

`$.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu",{allowSamePageTransition: true });`

and also download following css file, its a must for transitioning between pages/div elements

[jquery.mobile.transitions.css](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/ca9df1197a9748ee7448fb9b28c14c41d80d4601/themes/default/jquery.mobile.transitions.css)

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
if( data.status == "success" ) {
    window.location = 'index.html#mainMenu';
    return;
}
```

After refresh your page only html can run and only display your html not your server responce after refresh your page..And if you want to show your server response on your mainMenu div so you need to use Ajax call and after getting response so you write the code to display data in html..

Comment: i already have some daata in main menu, i just did not put in the code here and 
`window.location = 'index.html#mainMenu';`
work but does not display content

Comment: can you add your mainMenu code ? because it work fine for me.. so i think some thing is fishy on your html code may be :p

Comment: it does not contain anything except text saying "main menu", untill now

Comment: try again main solution.. i have added return keyword..

Answer (score 1):

**Try Using this Should Work**

```
  function loginPostData(jsonRequest)
    {
        alert("hello");
        $.post("http://localhost:8080/edserve/MobileServlet", 
                JSON.stringify(jsonRequest), 
                function(data) 
                {
                    var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
                    alert(obj);
                    if(data.status=="success")
                    {
                        $('#mainmenu').children().remove(); //clears div
                        $('#mainmenu').html(data);  //Loads data

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(data.message=="user not verified")
                        {
                            //display verification page 
                        }   
                    }   
                }, "json");
    }
```